# Lambda isn't returning the body with an http response to API Gateway

Tags: javascript, http, aws-lambda, nativescript, aws-api-gateway

Response shows just fine on Lambda alone when I perform a very simple query with http js module but when I call the function through API Gateway the body is returned empty, even after I put the result on the response body.

```
response = { 
           "statusCode": 200,
           "body": JSON.stringify(results),
           "isBase64Encoded": false
           };
           callback(null, response, connection.end());
```

From this I get:

```
{
"statusCode": 200,
"body": "[]",
"isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

on API Gateway but it shows as

```
{
"statusCode": 200,
"body": "[{\"id\":15,\"username\":\"3FWF34fWF\",\"password\":\"sha1$02f44ad2$1$c81a28b3217a4fb777850e85dbdfa088ab44266d\",\"email\":\"3514t34fg\",\"activated\":0,\"name\":\"fEEFEFAE4\"}]",
"isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

when I test the code on lambda.

Any help would be amazing. I am able to give more info anytime.

Comment: what type of integration are you doing? have you enabled `lambda proxy integration`?

Comment: Yes I did @ASR, it's enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue, the problem was the lambda function not reading the headers I was passing it correctly. Bare in mind that you can access to the event headers in lambda by using event.headers.

If you get this problem double check the event you are receiving on lambda by returning the whole event as a response instead of the actual results such as:

```
response = { 
       "statusCode": 200,
       "body": JSON.stringify(event),
       "isBase64Encoded": false
       };
       callback(null, response, connection.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue. I use python Instead.

```
   body = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "isBase64Encoded": False,
        "headers": {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        # "body": {"recc":response}
        "body":  response
    }
```

where the response in lambda is:

```
 "{\"55b7badc-75af-41c0-9877-af308264cb33\": \"0.4666666666666667\", \"4694e172-322e-4a51-930e-d3b9bfd3c2e6\": \"0.36363636363636365\", \"c5447cc5-936d-4aa6-97c4-3f51a7e7c283\": \"0.3\", \"6abf0893-5d32-4a43-942f-aaef4395d91d\": \"0.2727272727272727\", \"c0bf1214-fb41-48eb-b07d-f81b71ba0061\": \"0.25\"}"
```

Which is correct for api gateway, byt somehow I get:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "isBase64Encoded": false,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "body": "{}"
}
```